# How to concurrently load multiple ttl files as separate instances in jena-fuseki server

Tags: jena, fuseki

I am using apache jena fuseki server to load the data in a .ttl format and then querying the data.But the problem is i am not able to serve multiple data simultaneously.

I am starting the server using the following command.

```
 ./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

The server version i am using is 1.1.1

```
/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data **default** /home/user/data.ttl
```

I was thinking like if we change the **default** option in s-put command,is there any other options to serve concurrent data as separate instances.
    ./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data default /home/user/data.ttl

I am having a rest api from which multiple users can load the data and do SPARQL queries on top of it.But when each time a new user loads the data the server gets the new data and the previous data is gone.

I want each user to have his own data to be maintained by the server.Is there some mistake in the way i am loading data ?

Answer (score 1):

To add data, not replace it, use POST and command `s-post`.  HTTP PUT means "replace", HTTP POST is "append" (which forRDF just means "add").

PS Try Fuseki 2.3.0

Comment: the problem is if i use post i will be adding to the existing data. i need each user to  maintain seperate rdf/data. Is there any way to make it possible? so that each user can query the server based on users uploaded data.

Comment: Put the data in separate places - either separate graphs per user or separate datasets per user.

Comment: i am maintaining seperate .ttl files for each user. But when i am uploading the data, existing data is overwritten or gets appended as per your answer.But how to put in seperate places

Comment: I tried with a differenet graph name "test" like this.
/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data test /home/user/data.ttl
Error 400: Bad IRI: no IRI scheme name: test

Comment: POST http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/upload
400 No name for content - can't determine RDF syntax (35 ms)

Comment: I am able to load data in seperate graphs  /home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data http://example/test /home/user/data.ttl

But when i try to query the db using s-query command,it is still taking the default graph. How can i change this.

/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-query --service http://localhost:3030/ds/query  'sparql query to the data'

Comment: Either use GRAPH <...> to access a named graph Or you can make all the named graphs in dataset be a single union graph as the default graph.  See documentation on TDB.

Comment: . /home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-query --service localhost:3030/ds/query GRAPH<http://example/test>  'sparql query to the data' . is it the right way ?

Comment: can you post this answer including your last 2 comments  so i can accept it.